# Linking Malchut to Feet

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, parts-of-the-body, malchut-royalty

Does anyone have a citation (specific sefer with daf/se'if please) that links the concept of malchut to the concept of the feet?

Comment: Elimelech, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for bringing your question here! Could you please [edit] in information about why you suspect that such a linkage might exist? What prompted this question? Adding that would make it both more interesting and easier to answer informatively. Also, please consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features.

Comment: Well, many places in _Tanach_ speak of מלך אשור. cc: @IsaacMoses. −1.

Comment: @msh210, Ashur = feet?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Doesn't it mean "footstep" or something? I'd have to look it up in a concordance....

Comment: @msh210 I think you are thinking of Ashur not Ashshur.

Comment: ragleha yordot mavet - see zohar on this verse

Comment: Weren't king Asa's feet afflicted in his old age? Might be a place to look.

Answer (score 1):

It says in the [Eitz Chaim](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%92) " ואמנם החצונים הם יושבין תחת המלכות וקרובים אליה בסוד רגליה יורדת מות".

The reason is that (the bottom of) Malchus (of Atzilus) is enclothed within the lower world (of Briya).